# Flex 4.6: focus image on tab navigation

Tags: apache-flex, focus, custom-component, flex-spark

I have a MXML compoenent that is launched as a popup:

```
<s:TitleWindow>
  [...]
  <s:BorderContainer>
    <s:HGroup>
      two s:Button OK and Cancel
    </s:HGroup>
  </s:BorderContainer>

  <custom:box>

</s:TitleWindow>
```

custom:box looks like this

```
<s:BorderContainer>
  <s:Image source="{Util.getImage('error.icon')}" />
  <s:Image source="{Util.getImage('close.icon')}" />
  <s:VGroup id="messageContainer" />
</s:BorderContainer>
```

What I need is to add the close icon to the tab navigation and focus.

I've tried with `implements="mx.managers.IFocusManagerComponent"` to the custom:box as an attempt to change the focus on `focusHandler()`. I only get focus on the custom:box at most.

Also I've tried to set `buttonMode="true"` and `focusEnabled="true"` on the close image.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think an Image can get focus since it's not interactive. Try making it a real Button. If you don't want the Button chrome, just make a custom skin and remove all the unnecessary graphics.

Comment: I've went on with this approach, thanks.